# Spit array in Angular or js

Tags: javascript

I have some objects in an array that I need to split. Eg

```
[{"age":"3"},{"age":"5"},{"age":"4"},{"age":"5"}]
```

I need it to take however many inside the object and so it shows.

```
[3,5,4,5]
```

Comment: Did you try to solve it on your own ?
What did you try tilll now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
var arr =[{"age":"3"},{"age":"5"},{"age":"4"},{"age":"5"}];
var arr2 = [];

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
  arr2.push(arr[i].age);   
}
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Thanks, now I need  the  ["3","5","4","5"] to be [3,5,4,5] so the strings to numbers

Comment: add this line in for loop arr2.push(Number(arr[i].age));

Comment: Hey.. your solution works but I have just checked and it is a string. I'm getting it from a form "[{"age":"3"},{"age":"5"},{"age":"4"},{"age":"5"}]" can you remove all from a string to leave 3,5,4,5

Answer (score 7):

Splitting is not the correct action, I'd say you want to "map" the array, thus I'd suggest you use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var array = [{"age":"3"},{"age":"5"},{"age":"4"},{"age":"5"}];
var ages = array.map(function (item) {
    return item.age;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array using `map` and return the object property.

```
let parsed = array.map(e => e.age);
```

Comment: Harmony is really more readable, sadly since it is not available in most contexts yet, I think you should maybe add a note to specify it.

Comment: @Gianmarco https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: in what case is this usable?